# Deny users in a certain group access to dovecot

Tags: dovecot

I installed the `dovecot-imapd` package in Ubuntu, and my setup is as follows:

```
$ sudo dovecot -n
# 1.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-27-generic-pae i686 Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS 
log_timestamp: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S 
protocols: imaps
login_dir: /var/run/dovecot/login
login_executable: /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
mail_privileged_group: mail
mail_location: maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks: fcntl dotlock
auth default:
  passdb:
    driver: pam
  userdb:
    driver: passwd
```

For security reasons I would like to deny all users that are in the admin group ability to do imap login via dovecot. This is done in order to prevent a brute force attacker from discovering the admin passwords, and obtaining administrator privileges on the system.

How can this be achieved? Presumably, I will have to modify some settings in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`, but I am hesitant to change the default settings lest I create other security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got Dovecot configured to use pam.  This suggests that in `/etc/pam.d` you will probably find a file called `dovecot` that contains dovecot's authentication configuration.  You can put any pam modules here, including `pam_listfile`, which would let you deny services if a user is a member of a specific group.  The `pam_listfile` man page has some examples that might help out.